# Element php not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: php, html, css

Error: Element php not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
    <head><meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Witryna zstie</title>
    <style>
        html, body { margin:0; padding:0; color:black; background-color:grey;}
    #strona  { position: absolute; color: white; }
    #rects { position: relative; width:300px; height:125px;
         border: 1px solid #FF0000; color:yellow;margin: 5px; padding: 2px;}
    </style>
</head>



<body>
    
    <script>
        function clickbutton1(){
            document.getElementById("opis").innerHTML = Date();
        }
    </script>

<div id="strona">
<h1>Projekt tekstowy</h1>
<php>
echo "<p>zamiana danych wewnątrz przycisku";
echo "<div id='rects'>"
<!-- uruchomienie funkcji -->
<p id='opis'>opis wewnątrz</p>
<script>
document.getElementById('rects').onclick = clickbutton1; </script>
</div>;
</php>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Any ways to fix this error? [w3c validator]

Comment: It's `<?php ..... ?>` not `<php> .... </php>`, I think.

Comment: Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)

Comment: didnt change anything, still keeps throwing errors out

Comment: Did you use your source code, or the code produced by your webserver?

Comment: i used source code

Comment: Well, that won't work. The PHP needs to be interpreted by your webserver to produce valid HTML otherwise the w3c validator will complain about the PHP code.

Comment: As if you had not been told that a couple of months ago already, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70159908/#comment124049907_70159908

Answer (score 1):

You're not closing and opening the php tag right.

Original:

```
<php>
</php>
```

Change to:

```
<?php 
?>
```